# React: How to prevent user from entering 'e', '+' and '-' for input type="number"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, input, numbers

I have an input and can filter any letter if the input type is 'text'.
Also, I'm listening to an `onKeyUp` event to increment/decrement the input value.

But there are 2 issues with this approach:

1. The text input does not show up/down buttons on the right side.
2. When the user presses the 'ArrowUp' button, the cursor 'jumps' back and forth (to the beginning of the input and then jumps back to the end of it).

When I try to implement the same logic for numeric input, the value coming from it is empty when the user types "e". EG: '12e' will be identified as "" (empty string). That would be acceptable, but I want the user to be able to delete any values he/she entered by selecting the range and pressing the "delete" button.

Here is the code example I created to demonstrate the issue:

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-mcclintock-gd74y

**Update:**

According to an answer from Martin Wahlberg we should listen to an onKeyDown event.
Here is the working version that filters "e","-" and "+". Might be useful for someone who faced the same issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-fast-5u2qq

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const onNumberInputChange = useCallback(({ target: { value } }) => {
    if(!/\d*/.test(value)) return
    setFilteredValue(value);
    setUnfilteredValue(value);
  }, []);  const onNumerInputKeyDown = (event) => {
if(event.key === "e") event.preventDefault();
```

}

And if you update your number input to use this function on keyDown we should be able to stop the user from inputing e aswell

```
const onNumerInputKeyDown = (event) => {
    if(event.key === "e") event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Here the user will be able to delete their input completely and the user is prevented from using e.

Comment: Not really. If the user selects a whole input range and press 'delete', the input will not be updated.

Comment: What do you mean by pressing delete?  I cant see that you have added a delete button.

Comment: In your first version of the answer, the condition was if (!value) return. In this case, the user will not be able to select the whole range and delete it. I mean if the value is '341' and the user selects all 3 digits and press 'delete' on the keyboard, there will be no changes. In your second version of the answer, the condition is if(!/\d*/.test(value)) return which means that every time the user press the "e" button on numeric input, it will destroy the value. Because for some reason "e" is identified as an empty string that is equal to a deletion of the whole value.

Comment: I updated my answer. Think it should be a solution for you now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like number type fields interpret the `e` as part of a valid number using [e notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation). For example, `1e3` is the same as `1 x 10^3` or `1000`. It doesn't literally expand the number into the normal base 10 notation, but I guess when you end a number in `e`, it isn't a valid number.

By the way, entering a `+` also has the same effect as typing an `e`.

You can address this by updating your `onNumberInputChange` function to something like this:

```
const onNumberInputChange = useCallback(({ target: { value } }) => {
  const updatedValue = (value === "") ? filteredValue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') : value;
  setFilteredValue(updatedValue);
  setUnfilteredValue(value);
}, [ filteredValue ]);
```

Edit: I added the regex replace to handle when an `e` is inserted between numerals

Comment: In this case user will not be able to delete the whole value (select whole value + press delete button), it will not change it, because e in this case is equal to an empty string.

Comment: Sure enough - I thought I'd tested that case, but overlooked it... Is the specific requirement of what you're developing that you be able to use up/down to increment/decrement values and show the up/down arrow buttons in the input?

Comment: No worries! Thanks for your help! :)